# Woocommerce: Align add to cart button with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to align the “Add to Cart” button on the [shop page](http://seerahmuhammad.com/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A3-%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%86/) ? When the product names are different lengths. I try to add this CSS code but it is not working without hover.

```css
.woocommerce .products .product .button {
  font-size: 13px;
  /* padding:8px 26px; */
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute !important;
  display: block;
  bottom: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
.woocommerce a.added_to_cart {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  position: absolute !important;
  display: block;
  bottom: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to break the product name if the product name is long enough or use 'product name so long..... ' this way to display product name.or better to override the template archive.php on your child theme.